# how to simulate AppCompatActivity and ListActivity extend behaviors

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extend

Hello Guys I am looking for using AppCompatActivity for it's looking interface for downward compatiblity for api 8 and ListActivity since I am looking for onListItemClick override method of ListActivity so how can i do that.
e.g

```
public class a extends AppCompatActivity {
    //I want to use onListItemClick override method of class b with this   //instance if you get me
}
public class b extends ListActivity(){
  @override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
//some code here 
}
```

Thank you for your support!!

Comment: Well, you could just 1) add layout containing a ListView 2) in onCreate list = findViewById('idOfYourList') 3) list.setOnItemClickListener(...) .. Your Activity does not have to be of ListActivity type to be able to show a list and handle clicks, a regular Activity/AppCompatActivitiy does the same with a minimal amount of effort

Comment: Thank you I already choose option #3

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

### A Few Key Changes You Need To Make.

When switching from inheriting from `ListView` to `AppCompatActivity`, there are few changes that you need to make to replace what `ListView` had built-in.

1. You can no longer call `this` to get the `ListView`. You need to fetch it from the view. I recommend creating a method like this:

   ```
   protected ListView getListView() { return findViewById( android.R.id.list ); }
   ```

   *NOTE: If you list doesn't have an `id` of `list`, you will need to update it, but I recommend using the id `list`, if possible because it keeps it consistent and means you can use this method on more than one Activity.*
2. You can no longer just override the `onListItemClick` method because it doesn't exist on `AppCompatActivity` so you'll need to create your own listener and set it to the list with `setOnItemClickListerner` and add it to your `onCreate`. Here's an example:

   ```
   getListView().setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) { 
       Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition( position );

       String itemId = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "id" ) );

       Intent itemActivityIntent = new Intent( view.getContext(), Item.class );

       itemActivityIntent.putExtra( view.getContext().getPackageName() + ".itemId",  itemId );

       startActivity( itemActivityIntent);
     } ) 
   } );
   ```
3. You can no longer call `this.setListAdapter` in `populateListView`. Instead, you will need to fetch the ListView and call `setAdapter`, like this:

   ```
   getListView().setAdapter( adapter );
   ```

That should do it. There might be some other tweaks you need to make for your setup but those are big ones.